# Bot api, how i can get last message or chat history?

Tags: telegram-bot

I want implement some functional like user send me a message and I reply to him with my (bot) latest message from chat history.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73270188/8583692).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [Telegram Bot API Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) you can use `sendMessage` to send a message to the user.

When you receive a message, look for the `chat` or the `from` parameter in the JSON (depends if you want to answer to the person when it's a group chat or not). You can use the `id` parameter of the `chat` or `from` to send the message.

So the first parameter for your sendMessage would be `chat_id=message.chat.id`

You don't need the `parse_mode`, `disable_web_page_preview` and `reply_markup` for this example.

As you want to reply to the message of the user you may want to set the `reply_to_message_id` to the id of the received message.

```
reply_to_message_id = message.message_id
```

Last but not least, you want to set the `text` parameter. If I understand it correctly, your program will send the last received `message.text` to the user.

So what you want to do is, as soon as you get a message, save it.

```
Message oldMessage = message
```

And when you send the Message to the user use the old messages `text` property as the text.

```
text = oldMessage.text
```

Alright to sum it up here is the pseudocode of the function that will happen as soon as you receive a message:

```
Message oldMessage = null;

public void NewMessage(Message message){

    int chat_id = message.chat.id;
    int reply_to_message_id = message.message_id;

    String text = "There is no old Message"; //fallback value

    if(oldMessage != null){
        text = oldMessage.text;
    }

    //Send Message in this example only has 3 parameters, and ignores the 
    //not used ones
    SendMessage(chat_id,text,reply_to_message_id);

    oldMessage = message; //store the received message for future answering

}
```

As you store the whole message in `oldMessage` you could also set the text you will send to something like this:

```
String text = oldMessage.from.first_name+": "+oldMessage.text;
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use this code. If you just set `oldMsg = newMsg` if a second user sends a message to the bot it will appear "as if" the last user sent both. Use an array or object to store each user_id and his last_message instead.

Comment: This doesn't work if your bot is restarted mid conversation.

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to reply on users message you need this function:

```
public void sendMsg(Message message, String text){
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
    sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
    sendMessage.setText(text);
    try{
        setButtons(sendMessage);
        sendMessage(sendMessage);
    }catch (TelegramApiException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```