# Get last message/s from Telegram channel with Python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm using the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) library to write a bot in Python that sends URLs into a channel where the bot is administrator.

Now, I would like to have the bot reading, let's say, the last 5 messages (I don't really care about the number as I just need to read the message on the chat) and store them into a list in the code for further elaborations.

I already have my bot working with:

```py
bot = telegram.Bot(token='mytoken')
bot.sendMessage(chat_id='@mychatid', text=entry.link)
```

But I can't find a `bot.getLastMessage` or `bot.getMessage` kind of class into the python-telegram-bot library.

In case there's already no written class that does that, how can I implement it via the Telegram API as I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to API implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not possible in Bots unfortunately.
Here you can [find all available methods](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods) (that [`python-telegram-bot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) invokes behind the scenes) and there's no such method available to fetch messages on demand.

The closest you can get through the api is [`getChat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) (which would return the [`pinned_message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) in that chat).

What you can do in this case is, store the messages the bot sends as well as the message updates the bot receives (by setting up a handler) in some storage (database) and fetch from there later on.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will go through the database method

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the other type of Telegram API: [Telegram [client] API and TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram)?

Using [telethon library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) makes it easy to read channels history (see [telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/installation.html)).

For this, we need an `api_id` and an `api_hash`.  So, do the following:

1. Log in to your [Telegram core](https://my.telegram.org/)
2. Open the [API development tools area](https://my.telegram.org/apps)
3. Fill out the simple form there
4. Now you can receive your `api_id` and `api_hash`

See Telegram's help documentation about [how to get your API credentials](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id).

Here is an example code that gets the last *5* messages of *targetChannelId*:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient


API_ID = 123456     # See above for how to get it
API_HASH = '123abc' # See above for how to get it
client = TelegramClient('my-client', API_ID, API_HASH)


async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages('targetChannelId', limit=5):
        print(message.id, message.text)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The first time you run this code it asks your phone number or bot token. Enter your **phone number** in the format `+9912345...` where `99` is your country code and the rest is your phone number.
It then may send a login code to your Telegram app; enter it in the console.

**Note**: Only users (phone numbers) can see channel history messages; bots cannot (at least in telethon). Bots can only listen for channel **updates** only if they are one of its **administrators**.

The `client.iter_messages()` accepts other parameters like `min_id` which can be used to get messages only after a specific message (for example, we can save the last message id that we have processed and next time pass that id as `min_id` so only messages after that message are returned).