# how to read/receive telegram channel messages in my telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i'm trying to create a bot which can read/receive all messages in a specific channel and send them to me .
my problem here is that i can't find a way to access those messages in my bot

important thing is:

1. i'm not admin or creator of that channel
2. i don't want to ask the creator to add my bot as administrator

i've searched in google but i wasn't able to find a solution
and i'm also sure that it is possible to do it, because there are already some [junction bots](https://docs.junction.space/) with exact same performance .
any references or suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: All bots, regardless of settings, will receive all messages from channels where they are a member. [See here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73270188/8583692) for how to read channel past messages using a user account.

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out in the Telegram group of `python-telegram-bot`, bots can't receive messages from channels where they are not an admin. If you want something like this, you'll have to use a user bot, e.g. a program that controls your private Telegram account (in contrast to controlling a bot account). See [here](https://telegra.ph/How-a-Userbot-superacharges-your-Telegram-Bot-07-09) for some info on user bots.

Note that also the provider that you linked seems to be using userbots behind the scenes. More precisely, the docs on the so called ["DirectConnection"](https://docs.junction.space/direct-connection/) state that you need to enter a phone number (associated to a telegram account) and then "Follow the instructions" which probably just means to enter the verification code that Telegram sends you. Phone number + verification code is exactly what is needed to control your private Telegram account.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.